# How to display !contentAsset image in HTML editor component in communities?

Tags: lightning-community, community-builder

In a community builder, I have added an 'HTML Editor' to my Footer template section.

I am trying to display a link to an icon/image:

```
<div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/EFIPrint" target="_blank"><img src="{!contentAsset.facebook4xxl.1}" /></a></div>
```

but what I am getting is a broken link image:

[image]

The image itself is uploaded in the 'Files'/libraries section:

[image]

and is shared with 'All Communities'

what's the missing step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be the dashes in file name you need to recheck.
with an image "GetLogo.png" loaded to asset library i can refer it in HTML editor as below.

```
<img src="{!contentAsset.GetLogo.1}" style="width:100%;" />
```

note that it does not contain the file extension and has .1 appended to it.